# how to add a link to a document using rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest

Please help me in adding a "Link to a document" using rest api to document library

Comment: could you elaborate your requirement a little further? What do you want to do with the link exactly? Or would you like to create a link to a document which is stored somewhere else?

Comment: "Link to document" is one of the content types of document library..i want to add the link using rest api